# ReSharper 6 Plugin: Adding HighlightingInfos

Tags: plugins, resharper, resharper-plugins

I am currently writing a ReSharper 6 Plugin that should add `Warnings` to my IDE. These are read from an XML file with a LineNumber and other data.

So far I have created an `IDaemonStage` with `ErrorStripeRequest.STRIPE_AND_ERRORS` and a `IDaemonStageProcess`. This works and gets executed so far.

Problem is: The Warnigns don't get added to my IDE.
 **How do I get the correct TextRange and DocumentRange?**

In my `Execute()` I have this:

```
var violations = new List<HighlightingInfo>();
foreach (var error in errorsFromXML)
{
    // assignments here
    int lineNumber = 172; // example
    string ruleId;
    string rule;
    string error;
    rule = ruleId + ":" + rule;

    // I guess this is what's wrong
    var lineNumber = 
            JetBrains.Util.dataStructures.TypedIntrinsics.Int32<DocLine>.Parse(
                      linumber.ToString());
    int start = daemonProcess.Document.GetLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
    int end = daemonProcess.Document.GetLineEndOffsetNoLineBreak(lineNumber);
    var textRange = new JetBrains.Util.TextRange(start, end);
    var range = new JetBrains.DocumentModel.DocumentRange(
        daemonProcess.Document, textRange);
    // range.ToString() => (DocumentRange (6.253 - 6.262) on <WrongThread>) // example

    // and this should be fine again
    var highlight = new TqsHighlight(rule, error);
    violations.Add(new HighlightingInfo(range, highlight, Severity.WARNING, rule + id));
}
return violations; // returns various violations
```

Also I have a Custom Highlight Class:

```
internal class TqsHighlight : IHighlighting
{
    private readonly string error;

    private readonly string rule;

    public TqsHighlight(string rule, string error)
    {
        this.rule = rule;
        this.error = error;
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public string ToolTip
    {
        get
        {
            return this.error;
        }
    }

    public string ErrorStripeToolTip
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rule;
        }
    }

    public int NavigationOffsetPatch
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextRange` constructor actually takes an offset, which is probably not what you want. What you need to do instead is to call a few methods on `daemonProcess.Document`. Namely, if you call `GetLineStartOffset()` and `GetLineEndOffsetNoLineBreak()` this will get you the start and end of the line. You can cast an ordinary `int` to the required parameter type. Then, you can use these results to create a `TextRange` (use the constructor that takes both `startOffset` and `endOffset`) and, subsequently, a `DocumentRange`.

Hope this fixes the problem. Let me know if I can be of further help.

Comment: Thanks so far! I've just edited my question and corrected my TextRange, but I still don't see the stripes and my DocumentRange seems to be wrong `(DocumentRange (5.580 - 5.585) on <WrongThread>)`

Comment: Hi, I have tried this approach and it works just fine on my machine. Take a look at <a href="https://gist.github.com/1474476">this listing</a> for the example I used.

Comment: I think the missing part was the `StaticSeverityHighlighting` Attribute. It works fine now, thanks!